# Is it okay show some ids in html?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Is it okay to generate HTML page like this:

```
...
<div id='some_id' lesson_id='313'>
 ...
</div>
...
```

And in jQuery just do

```
lesson_id = $("#some_id").attr("lesson_id")
// send some AJAX POST requests with this lesson_id
```

Is it normal way to pass some data to js from server side ?

Many thanks!

Comment: rather use data-* attributes

Comment: There's nothing technically wrong with it, but it's invalid HTML.

Comment: What's the source of the lesson_id? Wouldn't it be more normal to use the same source? Also, I think you're asking two separate questions here: 1. Is it SAFE to show the IDs in html (would be visible when inspecting code in browser) and 2. Is it normal. Consider clearifying a bit! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `data` attributes:

`<div id="some_id" data-lesson_id="313">`

then in jQuery get the value:

`var lesson_id = $('#some_id').data('lesson_id');`

More about `.data()`: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Comment: Remember to mark as answer if it solved your problem/question, @EduardBondarenko . ;)

Comment: @chrisv I don't know that Samuel really _did_ answer the question. OP asked if the method used was fine, which it essentially was, and Samuel basically demonstrated how to use the `data-*` prefix, which was already mentioned in a comment by Bart earlier.

Comment: I know @harrisweinstein. But since OP did not answer my comment on his post, and the fact that he wrote: "awesome, thank you!" below this post, I guess he got the answer he needed?

Answer (score 2):

So long as it doesn't reveal any major information that a malicious user can exploit, you can do that. As has been said, though, you should add the `data-*` attribute prefix, as this allows you to have custom HTML that's still considered valid.

Answer (score 2):

Use [jQuery Data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

```
<div id='some_id' data-lessonid='313'>
 ...
</div>

lesson_id = $("#some_id").data("lessonid")
```

Comment: posting at the same time much @ochi

Comment: Furthermore, my apologies to @sef4eg -